# Bootstrap navbar - align an element in BOTH desktop and mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want some elements to be always displayed in the navbar - even when the menu is collapsed.

I use the standard navbar-bav class:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li>
      <div id="message" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

https://codepen.io/pepe007/pen/pwmyxZ

The problem: I want the div #message to be displayed left to the menu on both large and small screen.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NgVrom

Comment: Thanks, Michael!

Comment: no sweat, wasn't sure if that's what you wanted or not. I'll submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-arrange the elements, put them in flex rows, and use `margin-left: auto` on the mail icon to push it and the menu/dropdown button to the right.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4db07c8d8d.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <style>
    #logo {
      width: 250px;
      background: deepskyblue;
    }
    
    #popups {
      padding-right: 15px;
    }
    
    #user {
      display: inline;
      background: olivedrab;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    #message {
      display: inline;
      background: lightcoral;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .message {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .navbar-header, .navbarContainer {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    
    .container > .navbar-header {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
      margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }
    
    .fa-envelope {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .nb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
  </style>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container navbarContainer">

      <div class="navbar-header">


        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo">Brand</a>
        <ul class="nav pull-left">
          <li>
            <div id="user" class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav message">
        <li>
          <div id="message" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nb">
      
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-right navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">We are but visitors on this rock, hurling through time and space at sixty-six thousand miles an hour.</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Michael, I have just noticed that the "expand" button does not disappear when clicked (unlike in the original Bootstrap example). Moreover, the #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 div should be displayed below the existing header, not to the right of it. Can you help?

Comment: @Pepe the responsive layout in your pen seems wrong. The mail icon drops below the expand button. And I don't know what you mean "the expand button does not disappear when clicked" - it doesn't disappear in your pen? Took a stab at it tho, updated my answer. If that doesn't work you should post a new question, this question was just to get the message icon to the left of the menu.

Comment: you are right. My bad. BTW: Sorry I did not answer at once. Thanx.